# Set fileName for each e.target.files after uploading file

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add string for `e.target.files` name? For example:

```
document.querySelector('#document-upload').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
         selectedFiles[i].name = selectedFiles[i].name + 'test';
         imagesArray.push(selectedFiles[i]);
    }
});
```

When I upload file I want to add string to fileName. But now I get this error  `Cannot set property name of #<File> which has only a getter`

Comment: And why it got downwoted? Please share what is wrong with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file and set the name

```
document.querySelector('#document-upload').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
         imagesArray.push(new File([selectedFiles[i]], selectedFiles[i].name + 'test', 
             {
                 type: selectedFiles[i].type,
                 lastModified: selectedFiles[i].lastModified
             }
         ));
    }
});
```

Comment: Got this error ```Failed to construct 'File': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.```